# python: what does u'{' represent?

Tags: python

When I print out a value it has a `u` in front of it, I think it is some type notation, what is it? Where I can find a list of such notations?

Comment: http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It meant [*UNICODE string literal*](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code) before [Python 3](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit).

Documentation about all these literal adornments can be found [there](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals).

Answer (score 2):

[Unicode Constructors](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0100/) talks about unicode.

Answer (score 2):

That's creating a unicode string.  I'd recommend this section from [Dive into Python](http://diveintopython.net/xml_processing/unicode.html) on the topic

There are many advantages to explicitly using unicode, the most common reason for doing so is to force integrity when working with a database.